# Cant fetch anything from Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

i keep having trouble trying to set up redux, i have mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps set up and my actions and reducers but whenever i try to output any of my mapped props i cant fetch anything from the props i have mapped state to.

i went as far back as my index.js and tried using alert(store.getState()) and alert(store.getState().value1) and alert(store.getState(value1)) after i know that value1 has been dispatched, passed through my actions, my reducers and then (hopefully) into my store. I have also tried using alert on the prop i used in mapStateToProps

The only output i get is a blank alert for store.getState() and undefined for the other options.

I have no idea what is going wrong with my code :(

actions/index.js:

```
export const updateDial1 = (value1, value2) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_DIAL_1',
    value1,
    value2
  }
}
```

reducers/reducer.js

```
const update = (state, mutations) => Object.assign({}, state, mutations)

const valuesReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_DIAL_1':
        {
        return [
            ...state,
            {
                value1: action.value1,
                value2: action.value2,
            }
        ]
    }
}
export default valuesReducer
```

components/component.js

(taken out of the component)

```
// use this to apply values from redux store to local props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  valuesReducer: state
})

// use this to send changes to the Redux store
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateDialLine1: actions.updateDial1
}
```

and `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomComponent)`

index.js with store declaration: (the console.log returns an empty array)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Root } from './navigator/router';

import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import valuesReducer from './reducers/dials'

let store = createStore(valuesReducer)

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {

        // setTimeout(() => {console.log(store)}, 15000)

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Root />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side node, instead of debugging with `alert()`, favor `console.log()`. Even better in the present context, install the redux extension in your browser.

Comment: Could you add your store intialization ? I'd like to see how you register your reducers.

Comment: add that for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer code sample, you are assigning an array [ ] directly to state object. You should change your reducer code to following:

```
const valuesReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_DIAL_1':
        {
        return {
            ...state,
            {
                value1: action.value1,
                value2: action.value2,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the usage of {} instead of [ ] in the reducer.

If you need an array in your state object then add it as an object property:

```
const valuesReducer = (state = {myArray:[ ]}, action) => {return state}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the issue here, i already worked with array as reducer root state and it was perfectly fine.

Comment: i actually just got it all fixed about 30 minutes ago, but this answer was right :L